# PowerShell - Replace a specific string in xml file

Tags: powershell

After debugging I saw that the version was changed but not saved
How can I save the changes for the CDATA?

I added this: Its ok? Should I need the [0]? or the Parent?
Now only the CDATA is affected.... The second part stays as is

```
$CDATANodes[0].ParentNode.OwnerDocument.Save($xmlFile.FullName)
```

I have xml file that contains version number. I know how to replace a string in a file but here I need to find something that start with 8 and replace it with a number.
For an example

[image]

There are many places where the version 8.5.34.31.4 is displayed (There are more that not located in nodes.
I need to search something like 8. and replace it with another number like 8.5.34.31.5
For every xml the version is different (8.5.34, 8.6.22,...) So I thought to search the common beginning that is 8
Any idea how to do this?

[image]

```
$ReleaseVersion = '8.5.34.31.6'
$xmlFilePath = 'C:\Temp\BuildDescription.xml'


function ChangeVersionForRelease ([string] $ReleaseVersion, [string] $xmlFilePath)
{
# define the new version number
#$newVersion = '8.5.34.31.5'

# locate document on disk
$xmlFile = Get-Item $xmlFilePath

# use Select-Xml to read, parse, and query document for relevant nodes
$targetNodes = $xmlFile |Select-Xml -XPath '//*[starts-with(text(), "8.")]' 
if($targetNodes){
    $targetNodes |ForEach-Object {
        # replace the string contents of the node with the new version number
        $_.Node.InnerText = $ReleaseVersion
    }
$CDATANodes = $xmlFile | Select-Xml -XPath '//*/text()' | ForEach-Object Node | Where-Object NodeType -EQ 'CDATA'
    Foreach($CDATANode in $CDATANodes){
        $CDATANode.InnerText = $CDATANode.InnerText -replace '8(\.\d+)*',$ReleaseVersion
}

    # save to disk after modifying
    $targetNodes[0].Node.OwnerDocument.Save($xmlFile.FullName)
}
}

ChangeVersionForRelease $ReleaseVersion $xmlFilePath
```

All the nodes were replaced but not the CDATA. I got an exception

Select-Xml : Cannot convert value "C:\Temp\BuildDescription.xml" to type "System.Xml.XmlDocument". Error: "The specified node cannot be inserted as the valid child of this node, because the specified node is the
wrong type."
At line:21 char:30

- $CDATANodes = $xmlFilePath | Select-Xml -XPath '//*/text()' | ForEach ...
- ```
                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Select-Xml], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastToXmlDocument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectXmlCommand

I change from $xmlFilePath to $xmlFile and now I don't have an error but the replacement was not done. Maybe I don't save it?

Comment: Please copy/paste, as text, the code you are trying to make work, following the guidance in https://stackoverflow.com/help to provide an MRE (Minimal, Reproducible Example).